# Remove part of the border of a table excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, border, linestyle

There is a set of forms that we sometimes have to fill out at work, and I'm trying to automate the task by having excel VBA recreate the form as a word document and populate with the appropriate data and print as a pdf.  I'm getting stuck on removing the border line style.  I want there to be no border line on the left side.  I have tried different approaches, and the one that seems the most likely that it should work based on my understanding is below:
(note: ".Border(xlEdgeleft).LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone" is the line that is giving me trouble)

```
Sub main()

Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim objHdrRange As Object
Dim myTable As Object

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
Set objHdrRange = objDoc.Sections(1).headers(1).Range
Set myTable = objWord.activedocument.tables.Add(objHdrRange, 5, 5)

With myTable
    .Borders.enable = True
    .Border(xlEdgeleft).LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
   ‘more code goes here later
End With

Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objHdrRange = Nothing
objWord.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlEdgeLeft` and `xlLineStyleNone` are from the Excel Object Model, not from the Word Object Model, and you need the latter.

Since you are late-binding, you could add the following lines:

```
Const wdBorderLeft As Long = -2
Const wdLineStyleNone As Long = 0
```

and replace `xlEdgeLeft` and `xlLineStyleNone` with these, respectively.

See the [`WdBorderType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdbordertype) and [`WdLineStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdlinestyle) enum docs for more detail.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That was almost 100% correct.  There was one issue though and it was in my example.  I had the word "border" instead of "borders".  Apparently, it needs to be a borders object in order to run.